# How can I find the Next/Previous TreeViewItem of a treeviewitem on a button click event recursively in a TreeView like listview item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Finding next and previous element of a `TreeViewItem` in a `TreeView` in WPF. Is it really possible to find a `ListBox` item in a `ListView`? because if I iterate it the next item moves to the next level not the sublevels of the the current level? can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two methods for button clicks - moving up/down between siblings/children/parents:

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Parent is TreeView))
        {
            ItemCollection nodes = ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Parent).Items;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (nodes[i].Equals(myTree.SelectedItem))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (i < nodes.Count - 1)
                        {
                            ((TreeViewItem)nodes[i + 1]).IsSelected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Items.Count != 0)
                            {
                                ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Items[0]).IsSelected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Items[0]).IsSelected = true;
            }               
        }
    }

    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!(((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Parent is TreeView))
        {
            ItemCollection nodes = ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)myTree.SelectedItem).Parent).Items;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (nodes[i].Equals(myTree.SelectedItem))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            ((TreeViewItem)nodes[i - 1]).IsSelected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)nodes[i]).Parent).IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I have rather a hierarchical template with properties set to isSelected. In case I select a tree view item in the tree I want to get the index of it and find the next and previous item of the selected item programmatically.

Comment: What I need in my case is a feature that can simulate the behavior of arrow up/ down key with the help of two buttons on a treeview.

Comment: Okay for now I have added a method to list a parent and all children of the currently selected index. But to implement the 'arrows' you have to give me more information. I mean the 'up arrow' goes to the parent and 'down arrow' to first children or how are they supposed to work?

Comment: Consider any generic tree, having selected any item in the tree, and then using keyboard arrow keys e.g up arrow, it should go to up and select the sibling.and down key takes the user to the next sibling down the selected item.

Comment: So you do not consider moving between tree levels right? Or you want it to be possible only for the siblings on the edges meaning if Ceo in my example would have three managers (children), then selecting manager2 (the middle one) would only allow to move to manager1 and manager3?

Comment: I don't want to move any items in my tree. Consider it as a read only structure. It's only about moving selection up and down. Not moving them or changing their levels.

Comment: I know, whenever I said 'move to' i meant 'move selection to', so you want to 'move the selection' between siblings only or between levels as well?

Comment: Siblings and levels too.. That means when I am at the last child of a certain level.. Pressing down takes me to the next level

Comment: But you must know that certain children have different sublevels, so how would you move between them? Starting with first children sublevels or?

Comment: You can generalise it .. I have quite a generic tree.

Comment: I do not really get your intentions. Anyway You want to move just the selection on the tree?

Answer (score 0):

I had rather had a different approach to achieve the desired feature.
followed the link here : [http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com][1]

and then included the binary in my project references.

then click event of back and forward button, I sent keystroke UP and DOWN and achieved the required functionality.

```
public void upbutton_click(object sender, RountedEventargs e)
{
  treeView1.Focus();
  Inputsimulater.SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");
}
```