# Simulating behavior of arrow up/ down keys on a tree view with the help of two buttons in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am new to wpf. I have got a question. Can someone help me here. 
How can I Simulate the behavior of arrow up/ down keys on a tree view with the help of two buttons next and previous in wpf.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions on this website... we all saw your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358036/how-can-i-find-the-next-previous-treeviewitem-of-a-treeviewitem-on-a-button-clic)... instead, you should edit or add to your original question.

Comment: Well I thought it's not a duplicate question. It's just a different approach to the same question.

Comment: -1 Sure, you used *some* different words, but it's clear that you are asking for the same thing in both posts: how to find the next and previous `TreeViewItem`s with `Button`s. On this website, we don't continually ask new versions of the same question until we get answers. If we [don't get an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), then we tend to edit and improve our question, which will 'bump it' to the top of the new questions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Focus();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");
    }
```

focus the control then send the key to it

Comment: Which assembly I should include for sendkeys in my application ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the link as listed here, [Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com).